# How to hide a TextFields from multiple TextFields and set layouts or frame of other TextFields to remove space of hidden textfield?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I have been facing a problem since using auto layout. Before auto layout making multiple TextFields on a UIView  removing it by using code was very simple.But now a days, its very crucial to remove a TextField(UIButton,UIlabel) from multiple in a view and reset other TextFields by removing space of hidden TextFields.

So, can any one help me to hide a TextField from a view and reset other TextField by removing to space. In below image you can see my requirement-> I want to hide second TextField and rearrange below controls by managing(removing second TextField space)space and setting auto layouts of all below controls.

Please help me.

[image: Image for TextFields]

Comment: If you are not familiar with a UIStackView you should look it up.  It manages spacing for dynamic views like this where you need to remove an entire section.  When you remove a section from the UIStackView it automatically resizes itself, really easy to use and convenient object.  Check it out.